# GitHub: setting up separate development and production repos

Tags: git, heroku, github

I'm trying to setup a website on Heroku.

I'd like to have two separate repositories (**dev** and **prod**).
My local work would be be frequently pushed to the **dev** repo, and occasionally, I'd like to push/merge/fork from **dev** to **prod**, and then push **prod** to Heroku to update the server.
One suggestion I've received is to create a **prod** repo, then clone it to a new repo called **dev**, and then clone from **dev** to a local repository on my computer.
I'm not certain how to actually implement this, or if this is the right way to go.
For one thing, I would like **dev** to be stored on the GitHub server, and not on my local machine. Is that even possible?

If anyone has a different approach that they think will work better, I'd appreciate any advice.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with Heroku, but I would suggest using different branches rather than repos. Then you just need to merge `dev` into `prod` rather than pushing between two different remotes. Seems much easier to me

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate?

Comment: What I would do is synchronize the `master` branch with Heroku, and do all my development work in a dedicated branch, called `dev` or something. Whenever I was ready for a release, I would merge `dev` into `master` (In GitHub you could do this as a pull request; pull changes from `dev` into `master`). That way all of your website code is in one repo, and you don't have to worry about having two different remotes to push to. Just make sure to never checkout `master` locally, and you're golden

Comment: I imagine you could set up a commit hook between GitHub/Heroku to automatically pull changes into Heroku whenever `master` changes, but I don't know how; I'm sure Heroku has documentation for it

Comment: I've been told that it's preferable to push into the master rather than pull into it. But I'll look into what you've suggested. Thanks again!

Comment: I've never heard that; why do people say that's better?